# prevent loop from executing if variable is set

Tags: bash

I want to to execute an if statement a variable is set. I'm using bash.

Can I just use this statement:

```
if  [[ "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
```

Or is it better to use something like:

```
if  [[ ! -z "$user_lives_here" ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
if [[ -v user_lives_here ]]  ; then
    echo "variable is set"
else
    echo "variable is not set"
fi
```

Comment: ...if you have Bash 4.2 or newer.